# Replace figure content according to the item changes

Tags: beamer, itemize

I have one frame that generates three pages using `itemize`. Before the `itemize`, there is a figure that describes the current page.

There are total three figures (i.e., equiv_1, equiv_2, equiv_3) here for the three items, and these figures have the same size and similar content. What I want to is figure 1 is shown when it is the first page, and then figure 2 is shown at the same place (i.e., replace figure 1), when 2nd page is shown. and then similar for the 3rd page.

How can I achieve this? Thanks

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer} %beamer
\useinnertheme{rounded}
\usecolortheme{orchid}

 \mode<handout>{
   \usepackage{pgfpages}
   \pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm,landscape]
%   \pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1}[letterpaper,landscape,border shrink=5mm] 
  \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black!5}
%   \usecolortheme{dove}
 }

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf} 

\title{basdasd}
\author{as}


%\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{Unbcasa_1}}

\setbeamertemplate{sidebar right}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%

\hfill\usebeamertemplate***{navigation symbols}
\hspace{1cm}\insertframenumber{}/\inserttotalframenumber}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

\section{}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{MHDeS}
  MH Poo: transformation $\to$ unique MH chain.
  \includegraphics[scale=.1]{equiv}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item <1-> Create an Index Key for an MHG's root about to be created. 
    \item <2-> Find the chain
    \item <3-> Compar MHroot.
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\includegraphics<1>`

Comment: Can you provide the detail example? I am much newbie here..Thanks very much

Comment: I could if you add a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) to your question.

Comment: See my update on the sample code.. I have figures: equiva_1, equiva_2 and equiva_3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\includegraphics` takes overlay specifications:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{MHDeS}
  MH Poo: transformation $\to$ unique MH chain.
  \includegraphics<1>[scale=.1]{example-image-a}%
  \includegraphics<2>[scale=.1]{example-image-b}%
  \includegraphics<3>[scale=.1]{example-image-c}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item <1-> Create an Index Key for an MHG's root about to be created. 
    \item <2-> Find the chain
    \item <3-> Compar MHroot.
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```